# What is the origin of the terms L1 and L2?

Tags: terminology, history

As you no doubt already know, L1 refers to your first or native language, and your L2 is a second language. Your L3 language would be your third language, and so on. Where and when did the actual terms "L1" and "L2" originate? I researched on the Internet but I couldn't find a direct source.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

H. H. Stern in [Fundamental Concepts of Language Teaching](https://www.academia.edu/8375932/_Hans_Heinrich_Stern_Fundamental_concepts_of_lang_Book_Fi_org_) traces the L1/L2 distinction back to the 1959 article, *The teaching of English as a foreign language* by J.C. Catford:

> The ‘L1’/‘L2’ distinction was introduced by Catford in 1959. ‘One
>   may, for convenience, use the abbreviation “L1” for primary
>   language, and “L2” for secondary language. L1 is usually, but not
>   always, the language first acquired in childhood: it is the language of
>   its speaker’s intimate everyday life: it is also to a large extent the
>   language of counting and other forms of self-stimulation, or “thinking
>   in words”. Most people-that is all except perhaps ambilinguals-
>   have only one L1, but they may have a number of L2s, each
>   perhaps being reserved for one particular purpose, as, for instance,
>   reading scientific papers, enjoying a Mediterranean holiday, reading
>   the Scriptures.’ (Catford 1959: 137-8) The L1/L2 distinction became
>   popular, particularly in Britain, in the sixties (Halliday, McIntosh,
>   and Strevens 1964:77-9). It has maintained itself and is now quite
>   widely used in professional parlance in the English-speaking world.

Before 1959, *L* was already used to mean "language", especially in formalistic descriptions (e.g. Chomsky's 1957 *Syntactic Structures*). The earlist use (that I could find) of the name *L2* to denote language (though not a second language as we understand it today) was in the [1953 English translation of *Formal and Factual Science*](https://canvas.harvard.edu/files/1828793/download?download_frd=1&verifier=HFkOPiTqThgYhtYaYCubII5O17hDl60hmvAvlKbU) by Rudolf Carnap. It's hard to say whether these uses of *L* and *L2* influenced Catford.